# image tagging and add multiple link

Tags: php, javascript, image

I doing image processing project in php.I want to know about tagging.The facebook and orkut user can add link into different co-ordinate on a single image.i was try to implement using javascript,php and How to add multiple link on a single image. please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [tag map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp):

here is the text from that link:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```